# GAE dev environment attached to specific git branch

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm trying to set up a test environment for my nodejs app on Google Cloud Platform

I cannot find a way to mirror my repository's #dev branch using the "Automatically mirror from GitHub or Bitbucket" option which seems to automatically use #master and I cannot figure out how to change this behaviour.

I know it's possible to manually push local branch to a google cloud repo but in my setup this would be impractical.

I'd like `gcloud app deploy` to automatically deploy

`bitbucket.org:myproject/myrepo.git#dev`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default behaviour is to mirror the master branch at the moment, and the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories) mirrors this accurately in not mentioning branches. You should file a [Public Issue Tracker Feature Request](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list) for branch selection when setting up automatic mirroring.